# raspberry pi 3 - 3.5HDD - USB 2.0?

Tags: pi-3

I'm new to raspberry pi.

I have searched, but couldn't find a simple answer.

For the new raspberry pi 3, I would like to connect a 3TB 3.5 HDD; can the pi power and read/write to the drive through a 2.0 USB, from the network?

I intended to use it with a 3.0 SATA cable (I know it's useless..) like this one:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-SATA-Drive-Adapter-Cable/dp/B00HJZJI84/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1467724431&sr=8-3&keywords=usb+3.0+sata+cable

Any help/links are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work for two reasons:

1. To power a 3.5" HDD you need 5V for the electronics and 12V to spin the drive. A USB connector only provides 5V.
2. The USB 3.0 to SATA adapter cable is intended for use with 2.5" HDDs only. This is possible because 2.5" HDDs run with 5V but not 3.5" HDDs.

You will need to find an USB to SATA adaptor with a separate Power-Supply.